# Converting CFG to PDA for $S\to aSd|aBd\\B\to bBc|\varepsilon$

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

I need to build a pushdowm automata for the context-free-grammar

$$S\to aSd|aBd\\B\to bBc|\varepsilon$$

**My attempt:**

[image]

I'm not sure if my attempt is correct or not.